# wrote the editor user name in, after I editing the data in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a models which is about products

> models.py

....

```
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    ....
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if after I modify the data such as description or new image,,,etc. I would like the data useredit wrote the edit user name in,,

here is the edit thing function in

> views.py

```
....
@login_required
def edit_thing(request, slug):
# grab the object...
    thing = ProductsTbl.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404
# set the form we're using...
    form_class = ProductsTblForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
# grab the data from the submitted form
        form = form_class(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES,instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            # create an instance but do not save yet
            thing = form.save(commit=False)
# set the additional details
            thing.useredit = request.user

# save the object
            thing.save()

            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
# otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
# and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html', {
        'thing': thing,
        'form': form,
    })
....
```

however ,,, when I modified the thing information just shows the error below,,,.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/things/md0013/edit/

Django Version: 1.8.11
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('designer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/stayreal/sandbox/product_id/designer/views.py" in edit_thing
  52.             thing.save()
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/stayreal/sandbox/product_id/designer/models.py" in save
  60.         return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  827.                                       forced_update)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update
  877.         return filtered._update(values) > 0
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
  580.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1062.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  829.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  1028.                                     (field.__class__.__name__, val.__class__.__name__))

Exception Type: TypeError at /things/md0013/edit/
Exception Value: Database is trying to update a relational field of type CharField with a value of type User. Make sure you are setting the correct relations
```

how to wrote the editor name in database?  thank you

[image]

Comment: Please read comments on your last question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067756/get-success-url-takes-exactly-3-arguments-2-given#comment61681028_37067756

Comment: ok,,I try print("here") to trace,sorry,the full traceback I do not understand what does it mean?

Comment: Please *stop posting images*. Click the link that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view", and then paste the resulting traceback.

Comment: ok,,I did it,,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views.py change `thing.useredit = request.user` this to `thing.useredit = request.user.username`