# Django-registration-redux: get_success_url() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

New to Django.

I've been following Tango with Django so I'm surprised this error is happening. I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37067935/4624156) and changed my RegistrationView so it now looks like this:

```
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    success_url = 'home'
```

However I am still getting the same error. The user gets registered, but it shows the below stack trace.

**Full urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

from jam import views


class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    success_url = 'home'


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^jam/', include('jam.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="registration_register"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/change/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="auth_password_change"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/change/done/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="auth_password_changed"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Registration form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
<link href="{% static 'css/signin.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-3" align="center">Sign Up Here</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Yes, I have migrated.

**Full stacktrace:**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'haystack',
 'jam',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in dispatch
  33.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in form_valid
  37.         success_url = self.get_success_url(new_user)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: get_success_url() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to your question?

Comment: @KlausD. added to bottom

Comment: What version of `django-registration-redux` do you have installed?

Comment: In my site-packages: django_registration_redux-1.4-py3.5.egg-info

Comment: @JoshLaird something weird is going on, because looking at [the source code for `registration.views` on github for the v1.4 release](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/v1.4/registration/views.py) the lines in your stacktrace don't match up. I suppose it's possible that the tag in git doesn't match the release you ended up with. I'd look to see if the custom `get_success_url()` in the `RegistrationView` is missing, or has been overridden by a subclass (I haven't gone through Tango with Django, and you haven't provided a link to the steps you've done, so I can't guess which).

Comment: You were along the right lines. I uninstalled django-registration-redux and then re-installed it and I'm not getting this stacktrace anymore. It's possible I installed multiple versions somewhere down the line. If you put this in an answer, I'd be willing to accept it. Cheers!

Comment: (Although from the redux code and what you've posted, I doubt it's an problem with overriding.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127046/discussion-between-james-aylett-and-josh-laird).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling `django-registration-redux`? The line numbers in the stacktrace don't match the latest release from what I can tell from their github repository. This both makes it difficult to track down the problem without getting a complete copy of all your files and makes me worry that some of the registration code is perhaps not quite what it should be, either due to corruption or possibly not matching your Django version.